# Go to next aspx page using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, asp.net, postback, htmlunit, dopostback

I'm trying to parse an **aspx** page with **HtmlUnit** (Java). At the bottom of  each page, there are  tags to navigate to the next/previous page. In each page there are only 11 page numbers visible and one extra to go directly to the last page.

My problem is that even if I click on the 11th page, the HtmlPage cannot load the list with the next 11 page numbers... so I cannot parse for example the page #12.

*This is the initialization of the WebClient:*

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME, PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT);
webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(12000);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(60000);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
```

*This is the code that I use to click on an anchor to go to the next page:*

```
HtmlPage rootPage = webClient.getPage(url);
HtmlAnchor a = rootPage.getAnchorByHref(String.format("javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridViewAlbo','Page$%d')", page));
HtmlPage requestedPage = a.click();
```

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe1B8.jpg)

Comment: This is the page I am referring to http://www.ordinepsicologimarche.it/albo.aspx

Comment: Please read [Submitting JavaScript bugs](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html)

Answer (score 0):

I finally used [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and managed to parse all the pages.